# Blacklist users in Internet Facing Deployment of Dynamics CRM 2015

Tags: iis

I have:

- 1 internal application Dynamics CRM 2015 Server
- 1 internal web (IIS) Server
- 1 internet-facing web (IIS) server
- Both IIS servers connect to the internal CRM server
- Users are authenticated via ADFS

All users are able to authenticate via the internal IIS server.

Same for the internet-facing IIS server.

However there are a set of users that should not be able to authenticate via the internet-facing IIS server.

I cannot modify or touch the ADFS.

How can the user blacklist be achieved?

Comment: remove the iis facing the internet and buy an vpn appliance to give vpn access to the internal iis to vpn user that you configure. (as the authentification method is the same for both webserver, and that will secure your setup)

Comment: @yagmoth555 not an option

Comment: The authentification method kill you, as you dont have access to adfs either. The only solution possible would be a homemade portal, that iis authentificate, and you do another local validation if the username can remote. That make you maintain a local db

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the following file C:\Program Files\Microsoft Dynamics CRM\CRMWeb\web.config :

```
 <authorization>
    <deny users="DOMAIN\username"/>
 </authorization>
```

http://www.iis.net/learn/manage/remote-administration/configuring-remote-administration-and-feature-delegation-in-iis-7